# Loading classes for Reflections library outside Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, reflection, classloader

I'm trying to use the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) to give me a list of all the classes in a specific package in an external jar file. This works in Netbeans, but not when running the jar file from the command line. It looks like Netbeans finds and loads the classes I need, whereas the command line run doesn't. How should I set this up so it works everywhere?

I've tried both the usage example on the Reflections readme, as well as the response to [this issue.](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/263) Both methods have the same result.

Here's the test code I've been working with to reproduce the issue:

```java
package javaapplication1;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper;
import org.reflections.scanners.SubTypesScanner;
import org.reflections.scanners.ResourcesScanner;
import java.util.Set;
import org.externaljar.package.*;

public class JavaApplication1
{

    private static Reflections reflections;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String myPkg = "org.externaljar.package";

        URL[] urlPath = new URL[1];
        try{
        urlPath[0] = new URL("jar:file:/path/to/external.jar!/");
        }catch(MalformedURLException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        URLClassLoader urlLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urlPath);

        final ConfigurationBuilder config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .addClassLoader(urlLoader)
                .setScanners(new ResourcesScanner(), new SubTypesScanner(false))
                .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forPackage(myPkg));

        reflections = new Reflections(config, new SubTypesScanner(false));

        Set<Class<? extends ObjectBase>> objects = reflections.getSubTypesOf(ObjectBase.class);

        System.out.println("\n\nFound " + objects.size() + " Objects\n\n");
    }

}
```

Running the project in Netbeans gives a non-zero value for `objects.size()`, but running `java -jar JavaApplication1.jar` prints "Found 0 Objects". Adding `-verbose:class` to each shows that Netbeans loads all the classes I'm looking for, but those aren't loaded when run from the command line.

Comment: Is ObjectBase from that external .jar?

Comment: If so, then why you are creating another class loader when you already have that classes in your class path? as otherwise you would not be able to reference ObjectBase in this code. (I'm guessing this because of `import org.externaljar.package.*;` import) Please explain what exactly you want to achieve, as looks like you are loading classes from different places, you are looking for subtypes of `ObjectBase` loaded by your class loader in other class loader. And same classes but from different class loaders are actually different classes - so there is 0 results.

Comment: And otherwise... just make sure that this path to .jar is valid, as when running from netbeans it is probably running from different directory. You can also use `new File("path/to/jar.jar").toURL()` instead

Comment: Not an answer but check out [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph). It's a much more advanced library that serves a similar purpose.

Comment: @GotoFinal I was originally using the default classloader and just using `reflections = new Reflections("org.externaljar.package");` but that wasn't working and other examples suggested making a new classloader. 

As for why I'm doing it: `ObjectBase` is part of a publish/subscribe system. Each subclass overrides those methods differently, so I want to call `publish()`/`subscribe()` on each subclass without calling them all directly.

Comment: if you have that classes on your class path then creating separate class loader is not needed. Maybe you are shading these classes to different package? Hard to say anything without project, as it works fine for me and I can't reproduce your issue. Like someone suggested you can also just try ClassGraph instead - it's faster and have more options anyway